# Check if a database is well installed

Tags: database, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, eclipse

I tried to install wordpress under `eclipse` and `xampp` under ubuntu. I created the database (user: `root`, password: empty) by a sql command `create database wordpress;`, that is it.

The wordpress seems to work, because I can run and see that with `locallost` under a browser.

Then, I tried to install another wordpress projet (which works) that my colleague had already customised. He sent me all the wordpress files and a database file `asyc.sql`. I created another projet under eclipse and imported the database by the following command line:

`/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u wpuser -p wpuser asyc < asyc.sql`

And here is the result:

[image]

The database `asyc` does not seem to be well installed, though `wp-config.php` is well set in my opinion:

[image]

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to check:

1. Have you update the site URL in the wp_options table?
2. Once you log-in to wp-admin change the permalink structure and click save - this makes the system refresh all the links.

I personally always use MySQL Workbench to Export and Import data for MySQL databases as it makes life much easier.

Comment: Thank you... I have done some tests and updated the OP... For your first question, the `siteurl` of `wp_options` is still `http://localhost/wordpress` (my initial projet). Is it normal that I cannot see the projet of my colleague (`asyc`) in phpmyadmin? For the second question, I cannot log-in to wp-admin of the projet of my colleague due to the database problem.

Comment: So, the site URL should really be the new one [http://localhost/sun] or at least from your screenshots above that is what I would expect it to be.  Secondly - you are right, you should see a database called 'asyc' in phpmyadmin.

Comment: So that means `asyc.sql` was not well imported... how should I import it?

Comment: I'm not massively good with phpMyAdmin but from memory you have to click New above "information_schema" on the left.  Create a new database called "asyc" etc.  Select it on the left once you have done all that so it is "in use" - an import tab will appear where you can then upload your .sql file....

Comment: I successfully imported the file (by `Import` button) by phpmyadmin, the site now works... thank you...